# How to deal with a small extra cluster in a tabular data?

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, feature-scaling, outlier

I am working on a high dimensional tabular dataset with 1600 features and 9440 rows. No matter how I select the features, when I try to project my data into a 2d or 3d graph using dimensionality reduction techniques like UMAP or PCA, I can see there are two clusters of data. One of them is a bigger cluster with the majority of the data and the other one is a smaller cluster causing the accuracy to drop. If I remove those small clusters, I get a very high accuracy of over 99%, but I cannot drop the rows as it's a requirement. I used an elliptical envelope algorithm to remove the second cluster.

Now I've tried all the common scaling methods like StandardScaler, MinMaxScaler, Robust Scaler and a few more. Nothing seems to work. I am out of methods to use and need suggestions to improve my model. Any inputs are appreciated.

I am working on a supervised learning model.

Comment: what is your goal ?

Comment: Accuracy doesn't indicate a good model. In many classification problems, a large percentage of the data is easy to classify. The fact that some of your data ruins your near-perfect accuracy is very likely because those unruly data points are the reason this problem is interesting and worth your time in the first place. Discuss your thoughts with someone who can help you understand how the outputs of this classification project will be consumed.